# Where can I find used servo/stepper motors?

Tags: stepper-motor, servo

For practicing purposes (Arduino and other controllers), from what old equipements can i recover (recycle) small servo/stepper motors?

- Maybe old printers...?

Comment: Old RC toys? \${}{}{}\$

Comment: Stepper motors are fairly common. Servos? Good luck.

Comment: Small servos are fairly cheap, in the $10 range. See http://www.pololu.com/product/1053 for example.

Comment: Some 5.25 floppy drives (Teac) have nice steppers.

Comment: Shopping questions are a NONO here, but a shopping comment might be OK: you might check hobbyking.

Comment: The OP is not asking where to ***buy*** stepper motors, but instead asking where to ***salvage*** them from. [This has already been determined to be **on-topic**](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2658/2028).

Comment: Discarded ink-jet printers can be a source of salvageable stepper motors.  But, as with many components salvaged from modern China-made gadgets, you might have a difficult time finding the specs or the datasheets.

Comment: That was not a question about where or what to buy, but where to find old used servo/stepper motors for use with Arduino project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DC Servos:
RC Servos, pretty cheap to buy new.

Stepper motors:

- Printers
- Scanners or photo copiers
- Air Conditions, the "flap" thing that directs the air are usually controlled by a stepper.
- Cars, speedometers and ventilation sometimes use steppers. Google speedometer repair kits.